# Django: How to use a custom social-auth backend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I have overridden the GoogleOAuth2 class in django social-auth.
Currently the new class is in views.py.

But I cannot find how to add it to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in settings.py

I have tried like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    '_auth.backends.YouTubeOAuth2', <---------- new backend
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

And adjusted the template:

```
window.open('{% url 'social:begin' 'youtube' %}', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

In the end of the Google auth process comes an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError at /api/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/
> No module named '_auth'

Comment: Does changing the import order do anything? I mean, having `'_auth.backends.YouTubeOAuth2'` after the 3 `social_core` imports

Comment: Values in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` must be valid import paths. Verify that you can import the module in a Django python shell by doing  `from _auth.backends import YouTubeOAuth2`

Comment: @omab i checked in the shell and it returns the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_auth'

Comment: Right, you need to solve that import path, the `_auth` module must be available in your python import path, could be in your `PYTHONPATH` or your Django root module, where in your project is located `_auth`?